# How to move mouse pointer onto a webelement is selenium webdriver java

Tags: java, selenium, canvas

While testing a HTML-5 canvas, I have to move the mouse over the internal canvas elements for visibility. What I'm doing now is

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.mouseMove(aX, aY);
```

The cursor is moving on the wrong place , its moving on top of my screen rather than on the canvas. I tried a couple of ways which include

`1) robot.mouseMove(webelemnt,intx,inty)` This isnt supported.

```
2)Actions builder1= new Actions(driver);
builder1.moveToElement(webelemnt, aX, aY).click().perform();
```

this shows an error "Offset within element cannot be scrolled into view: (0, 0)"

Can someone suggest me .

Regards,
Sampath

Comment: The variables aX and aY, what are they being set to?

Comment: They are the positon on the canvas where the mouse is supposed to be moving. not on the entire screen . only with respect to the particular web element

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use Webdriver for similar mouse event simulation but sometimes it works not as expected. If it is possible for your case, you can try to use JQuery functions: onmouseover(), onmouseenter(), mouseout().